# How to remove h2 tag from html data using beautifulsoup4?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to remove the h2 tag what i am getting after removing applying the following script. I have been using beautifulsoup to get data from the website.

```
url = 'http://diningdelights.in/Normal-mum.aspx'
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(url)

def select_form(form):
    return form.attrs.get('id', None) == 'form1'
br.select_form(predicate=select_form)
br.form.set_all_readonly(False)
br.form["hdnPageSearch"]='3'
br.submit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(br.response().read())

for g_data in soup.find_all("div", class_="innerContainer"):
    h2_data=g_data.find_all("h2")
    print h2_data
```

I am just getting data inside the h2. for example.

```
<h2> Evergreen </h2>, <h2> Evergreen</h2>
```

could somebody help how i can remove the following tag.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the elements; if you want the text *in* the element, then retrieve that. For example, with the [`.string` attribute](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string):

```
print h2_data.string
```

You can simplify your search using a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for h2_data in soup.select("div.innerContainer h2"):
    print h2_data.string
```